# Derivative of $a^{x^{1/2}}$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I know that derivative of $a^x$ is $\ln(a)a^x$ but is there a rule which applies to $a^{x^{1/2}}$ or do I have to manipulate power of x with taking ln of both sides in order to find it?

Comment: You could use the chain rule.

Comment: Do you mean $a^{x^{1/2}}$ or $(a^x)^{1/2}$?

Comment: Please, use Tex notations. If you don't know how, here is the tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @J.G. I edited the post correctly I guess, the first one I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a simple Chain Rule:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} a^{x^{1/2}} &= \ln(a) a^{x^{1/2}}(x^{1/2})’\\
&= \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\ln(a)a^{x^{1/2}}.
\end{align*}$$

Alternatively, recall that $a^b = e^{b\ln(a)}$. Thus,
$$a^{x^{1/2}} = e^{(x^{1/2})\ln(a)}$$
so
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx} a^{x^{1/2}} &= \frac{d}{dx} e^{x^{1/2}\ln(a)}\\
&= (x^{1/2}\ln(a))’e^{x^{1/2}\ln(a)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\ln(a)(a^{x^{1/2}}).
\end{align*}$$

Alternatively, we can use logarithmic differentiation. Letting $y=a^{x^{1/2}}$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\ln y &= x^{1/2}\ln(a)\\
\frac{d}{dx}(\ln y) &= \frac{d}{dx}(x^{1/2}\ln(a))\\
\frac{y’}{y} &= \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\ln(a)\\
y’ &=\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\ln(a)y\\
y’ &= \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\ln(a)(a^{x^{1/2}}).
\end{align*}$$

In general, by the Chain Rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx} a^{f(x)} = \ln(a)a^{f(x)}f’(x).$$

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation and $(a^b)'=\exp(b\ln a)'$ are exactly the same.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire No, they are not “exactly the same”; because in the former, you are differentiation $b\ln a$ by itself; in the latter, you are using the derivative of the exponential function. They amount to doing about the same work, but they are not “exactly the same.”

Answer (score 0):

Using the "chain rule", as Eevee Trainer suggested, let $y= x^{1/2}$.  The $f(y)= a^y$ so $\frac{df}{dy}= a^y \ln(a)= a^{x^{1/2}} \ln(a)$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$.  The chain rule then says that $\frac{df}{dx}= \frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}= \left(a^{x^{1/2}} (a)\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\right)= \frac{1}{2} \ln(a) x^{-1/2}a^{x^{1/2}}$